# Rails 4, Turbolink execute javascript after render a partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form configured with some javascript. The javascript is loaded on load event handled by Turbolink:

```
//app/assets/javascripts/init.js
var ready = function () {
    App.init(); //I configure some components of _form.html.erb partial
};
$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

If I render a partial the `App.init()` code is not execute and my application is not well configured.

```
//new.js.erb
$("#my-modal").html("<%= j( render 'form') %>");
$("#my-modal").modal("show"); //The partial is inside a modal
```

Can I execute the code after the partial is rendered?
Something like this:

```
$(document).on('partial:render', ready); //Concept
```

In need to execute the js code after the partial is render becouse I need to configure some Jquery plugin to customize the modal form.

The modal is a classic Twitter Bootstrap modal:

```
//_form.html.erb
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
          <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">new</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <%= simple_form_for(...) do |f| %>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <ul class="errors"></ul>
          <%= f.error_notification %>

          <%= render "companies/fields", f: f %>
          ...
          ...
        </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried "page:change" instead of "page:load"

Comment: Yes, see the comment in the next answer

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(document).on('page:change', function () {
  // Actions to do
});
```

In your case simpley replacing the 'page:load' line in your js call with:

```
$(document).on('page:change', ready);
```

Comment: I can not use your solution becouse the event change is triggered every time a page change, but I want to execute App.init() only when a partial is rendered

Comment: Are you opposed to adding the App.init js call inside the partial view?